# Best practices for Joomla - Get another model in a view from another controller

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, custom-component, best-practices

I need to get data from another model than the view specific controller/model into the view. But I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it now is correct.

I do that via the following way in the view.html.php file:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'components' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'com_mycomponent' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models');

//get instance of model class, where class name will be fooModelBar
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Messages', 'MyModel');

//call model method
$this->messages = $model->getData();
```

But I have a feeling this is not the "correct" way to handle things. Can anyone educate me where I actually have to put this code? I know I am probably not doing it correctly by adding the model to the view.html.php file, but I am a bit confused where I need to add it. I tried adding a display() method to the profile controller but that didn't do anything.

Comment: By posting resolving advice as an edit, your question becomes a code review.  This is perfectly okay, but I recommend that you edit the question again to remove the initial / failed coding attempt.  Only showing the working code and purely asking for refining advice will make your question leaner and more attractive to read.  Your title, too, can be improved -- specify that you are seeking "best practices".  (We even have a tag for `best-practices`.)

Comment: Okay, sorry I wasn't aware of that, I just came up with the solution while I asked the question before.. I will try to edit the question and make it a code review instead of a question

Comment: No worries, I'm just trying to help.  You have done the right thing by continuing to pursue a working solution.  I prefer to have my own code reviewed / validated so that I can learn the best techniques and also learn if I am making any glaring mistakes.

Comment: Is the View displaying data from two or more models, i.e. the normal view model and the 'messages' model in your example?

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to update your code to move away from JModelLegacy and by placing the `addIncludePath` in the subcontroller using the following lines.

**mycomponent/controller/messages.php**

```
Use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\BaseDatabaseModel;
.    .    .
BaseDatabaseModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_mycomponent/models');
$this->msgsModel = BaseDatabaseModel::getInstance('Messages', 'MyModel');
```

Alternatively you can use `$this->addModelPath` from the BaseController class that your controller may already extend, which issues the above addIncludePath statement, see `/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController` at line 143. However the `addIncludePath` statement may not actually be required if the model directory is already in the path of your component.

By setting the `$this->msgsModel` in the subcontroller you should be able to call the model in the sub controller, another Model, a Helper, other code file or View(although probably not recommended under MVC rules) easily.

```
//call model method
$this->messages = $this->msgsModel->getData();
```

The View should only access `$this->messages` to get the data as it should not be concerned with how or where `$this->messages` is created.

Ignoring the comment about FooModelBar I would say you need to create a file called `/component/com_mycomponent/models/messages.php` with a class name of `MyModelMessages` to hold the code of your Model. Because you aren't following the Joomla naming convention so that it can be automagically resolved, you can use whatever replacement you choose for `MyModel`.

Comment: Is this still considered best practice now that Joomla 4 has released? I noticed that the comments in the legacy model wanted the use of MVCFactory as a replacement.

Comment: @Chaosxmk I believe it is still an acceptable way to add a model, whether it is Best Practice is very subjective. Only the addIncludePath is depreciated in Joomla 5, BaseDatabaseModel and addModelPath are not flagged as being depreciated in the foreseeable future. I am not familiar enough with Joomla4 yet to know if an alternative or improved method is available.

Comment: alright, well I guess for now it's best to proceed with this until the documentation for Joomla 4 is done and more time has been had using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$model     = $this->getModel('name');
$getMethod = $model->myFunction($someParams);
```

Comment: Your answer has been flagged by the system as being low-quality.  Please be more generous when you post.  Please always explain every snippet that you post so that the OP and thousands of future researchers not only receive a solution, but an education as well.